# Why does my code only work when I comment out "break;"?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a LeetCode question ([26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/)) and my code was not working until I commented out "break;". Could someone explain why this is so? Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
    public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
        int read = 0;
        int write = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int found = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if ((nums[i] == nums[j]) && (i != j) && (j < i))
                    found = 1;
                   // break;
                }
            
            if (found == 0) {
                nums[write] = nums[read];
                write++;
            }
            
            read++;
            
        }
        return write;
    }
}
```

Comment: code needs to stop if it finds the same numbers, thus needs a break statement. If there is no break then it will continue until j=num.length or i=num.length, and removes last duplicates.

Comment: You could also use streams if you're on a java version > 8:
int[] nums = {0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4};

return Arrays.stream(nums).distinct().toArray();

This should do the job too and is way more concise and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your code correctly, and you'll see that the corresponding part reads as:

```
            int found = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if ((nums[i] == nums[j]) && (i != j) && (j < i))
                    found = 1;
                break;
            }
```

You can see, that the `break` is not only executed if the condition holds true but in every iteration, so also in the first one. The loop terminates as soon as you've inspected the case `j == 0` which is incorrect, of course.

As you want to terminate the loop only if the condition holds true, just put the two lines after the if-statement into a code block:

```
            int found = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if ((nums[i] == nums[j]) && (i != j) && (j < i)) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                } 
            }
```